# Вопрос по классам java

Tags: java, ооп

вопрос состоит в следующем: мне нужно получить список месяцев и их номеров (обычный ArrayList, состоящий из объектов с двумя полями - название месяца и его номер). Пример одного элемента: ("январь", "01").
Так вот, могу ли я создать класс `Month`, внутри которого будет статический метод `getMonths()`? Будет ли это правильно, или есть более грамотное решение?
Пример кода:

```
public class Month {
    private String name;
    private String number;

    public Month(String name, String number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public static List<Month> getMonths() {
        List<Month> list = new ArrayList<Month>();

        list.add(new Month("январь",   "01"));
        list.add(new Month("февраль",  "02"));
        list.add(new Month("март",     "03"));
        list.add(new Month("апрель",   "04"));
        list.add(new Month("май",      "05"));
        list.add(new Month("июнь",     "06"));
        list.add(new Month("июль",     "07"));
        list.add(new Month("август",   "08"));
        list.add(new Month("сентябрь", "09"));
        list.add(new Month("октябрь",  "10"));
        list.add(new Month("ноябрь",   "11"));
        list.add(new Month("декабрь",  "12"));

        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: можно придраться, но в целом это нормально

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Поскольку месяцев строго ограниченное количество, вполне вероятно, что вам больше подойдет enum.

```
public enum Month {
    JANUARY("январь", "01"),
    FEBRUARY("февраль", "02"),
    MARCH("март", "03"),
    APRIL("апрель", "04"),
    MAY("май", "05"),
    JUNE("июнь", "06"),
    JULY("июль", "07"),
    AUGUST("август", "08"),
    SEPTEMBER("сентябрь", "09"),
    OCTOBER("октябрь", "10"),
    NOVEMBER("ноябрь", "11"),
    DECEMBER("декабрь", "12");

    private String name;
    private String number;

    private Month(String name, String number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public static List<Month> getMonths() {
       return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Month.values()));
       // либо Arrays.asList(array), если не требуется в дальнейшем модифицировать список
    }
}
```

Comment: а для чего используется конструктор и поля `name, number`?

Comment: @FarkhodDaniyarov это вопрос к asssin2. Очевидно, у него есть геттеры для этих полей, которые он опустил.

Comment: благодарю за ответ, да, есть сеттеры и геттеры, но они "про запас", пока не нужны)

Comment: @Nofate если Вам вдруг это интересно - у Вас ошибка в профиле (ссылка на гитхаб)

Answer (score 1):

Ну коль скоро имеем дело с постоянными величинами, то наверное лучше поступить как-то так:

```
public class Month {
    private static final List<Month> MONTHS = Arrays.asList(new Month[] {
        new Month("январь",   "01"),
        new Month("февраль",  "02"),
        new Month("март",     "03"),
        new Month("апрель",   "04"),
        new Month("май",      "05"),
        new Month("июнь",     "06"),
        new Month("июль",     "07"),
        new Month("август",   "08"),
        new Month("сентябрь", "09"),
        new Month("октябрь",  "10"),
        new Month("ноябрь",   "11"),
        new Month("декабрь",  "12")
    });

    public static List<Month> getMonths() {
        return MONTHS;
    }

    private String name;
    private String number;

    public Month(String name, String number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

Т.е. не надо ничего создавать каждый раз, чтобы получить одинаковые месяцы, одинаковые списки месяцев. Всё что нужно заготавливается один раз и навсегда.